# Dependent objects for New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Tags: powershell

We created multiple powershell scripts that read from word document and extract required information.

Locally on laptop all works fine, but when we deployed on production server.... they dont work.

We run powershell scripts through asp.net web app... that's where any powershell scripts that refers to `WORD.APPLICATION` are not working

Components we deployed on production server:

- operating system: Windows Server 2012
- Powershell: Version 5
- MsOffice 2010 installed
- Asp.net 4.5 all components installed

We have created web application in ASP.NET 4.5 Core where user upload documents and based on certain criteria documents will be searched for specific keyterms. if keyterms found, values will be displayed.

Asp.net invokes powershell script which has all document library code to search through. Everything gets executed in PS script, except where WORD-APPLICATION code is referred.

Has anyone faced any issues while deploying them on server?

Comment: Does your server have word installed?  Is your web app dotnet CORE?  There aren't enough details here.  How does this relate to powershell?  Where is the code that's failing? Exception messages?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - add more comments. We don't get any error message on why its not able to invoke this - New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Comment: Why aren't you using the powershell library in your web app?  [Here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) and [a good article to go alongside](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Required reading:

> <sub>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office</sub>
>
> All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.
>
> ...
>
> Besides the technical problems, you must also consider licensing issues. Current licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office. Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA).

As you can see, the scenario you're trying is officially unsupported, and license wise **very** expensive, as you officially require an Office license for each user invoking your functionality or for whom you're invoking the functionality.

There is an official Open XML SDK, which will allow server-side processing of the XML-based office documents:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/word-processing

If that isn't enough, there are a number of 3rd party libraries that provide server-side execution and don't require office licensing, some commercial, some open source:

- Aspose: https://www.aspose.com/
- NPIO: https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI

There are ways to get your code working on the server from an ASP.NET Application. They are officially unsupported, they open up your server to a number of extra security issues, they are very expensive from a licensing perspective and there is no guarantee they will remain working.